# Understanding a statement about the series $S =\sum_2 ^\infty \frac{1}{n\ln n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

In *Mathematical Methods for Physicists*, the author writes the following with reference to the series $S =\sum_2 ^\infty \frac{1}{n\ln n}$:

> We form the integral $\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{x\ln x} dx$ which diverges, indicating that $S$ is divergent. Because $n\ln n \gt n$, the divergence is slower than that of the harmonic series.

So far so good. He further writes:

> But because $\ln(n)$ increases more slowly than $n^\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ can have an arbitrarily small positive value, we have divergence even though the series $\sum_n n^{-{(1+\epsilon)}}$  converges.

This is the part that confuses me.
Perhaps the author is referring to the comparison test. It is known that $\sum_n n^{-{(1+\epsilon)}}$, i.e. $\sum_n \frac{1}{n.n^\epsilon}$ converges since $1+\epsilon \gt 1$. It would suffice to prove that $n\ln(n) \gt n.n^\epsilon$. For this we compare how fast $\ln(n)$ and $n^\epsilon$ increase with $n$. Let's take their derivatives, $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{\epsilon}{n^{1-\epsilon}}$. Now we do not know the nature of $\epsilon$. How do I proceed with the conclusion?

Comment: The author presented several statements: (i) $S$ diverges by comparing with $\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{x\ln x} dx$; (ii) $S$ grows slower than harmonic series; (iii) $S$ grows faster than $\sum_n n^{-{(1+\epsilon)}}$; (iv) $\sum_n n^{-{(1+\epsilon)}}$ converges. There is no contradiction (as expected), and (iii) (iv) don't imply (i) directly. Example: $\sum_2 ^\infty \frac{1}{n(\ln n)^2}$.

Comment: There are many other convergence tests. The Cauchy Condensation Test works for $\sum_n 1/(n\log n)$.

Answer (score 2):

By $n\ln n < n^{1+\epsilon}$, thus $\sum \dfrac{1}{n\ln n} > \sum \dfrac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}}$. The series $\sum \dfrac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}}$ converges. This cannot be conclusive about the convergence of $S$, because $S$ is bigger than something finite then we don't know if $S$ is finite or infinite. Hence, you should use integral.

Comment: How did you conclude that $nlnn \lt n^{1+\epsilon}$ without knowing the nature of $\epsilon$?

Comment: Formally they meant that for every fixed $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $n_0$ such that for all $n > n_0$ we have $n \ln(n) < n^{1 + \epsilon}$.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid all confusions and sticking to explanations using words like "faster" and "slower" which reduce the rigour of the argument you should directly look into the [Integral Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20integral%20test,as%20the%20Maclaurin%E2%80%93Cauchy%20test.) or the [Cauchy Condensation test.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)

By Cauchy Condensation test it suffices to check convergence of the series $\sum \frac{2^{n}}{2^{n}n\ln(2)}=\sum \frac{1}{n\ln(2)}$ which diverges as $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ is divergent.

Comment: It cannot be true that $\frac 1{n\ln n} \geq \frac 1 n$. To prove that $\sum \frac 1{n \ln n}$ diverges, it is not enough just to compare it with $\sum \frac 1 n$. You need to compare it with an integral.

Comment: Thanks for answering.All my confusion stemmed from the existence of $\epsilon$ in the equation. Could you please edit your answer accordingly?